# Prisma error: Invalid `prisma.userApiLimit.findUnique()` invocation:

Tags: typescript, next.js, schema, prisma

I am getting the error while redirecting on my, dashboard, i am also checking for subscription so that user cannot use more than max_free_counts but instead of redirecting, i am getting an error.This my api-limit code, plzz have a look:

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { MAX_FREE_COUNTS } from "@/constants";

export const incrementApiLimit = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: { userId: userId },
  });

  if (userApiLimit) {
    await prismadb.userApiLimit.update({
      where: { userId: userId },
      data: { count: userApiLimit.count + 1 },
    });
  } else {
    await prismadb.userApiLimit.create({
      data: { userId: userId, count: 1 },
    });
  }
};

export const checkApiLimit = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return false;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: { userId: userId },
  });

  if (!userApiLimit || userApiLimit.count < MAX_FREE_COUNTS) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

export const getApiLimitCount = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return 0;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: {
      userId
    }
  });

  if (!userApiLimit) {
    return 0;
  }

  return userApiLimit.count;
};
```

For schema.prisma, this is the error i am getting, plzz checkout and let me know where am i going wrong,

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model UserApiLimit {
  id        String      @id @default(cuid())
  userId    String   @unique
  count     Int      @default(0)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model UserSubscription {
  id        String      @id @default(cuid())
  userId    String   @unique
  stripeCustomerId       String?   @unique @map(name: "stripe_customer_id")
  stripeSubscriptionId   String?   @unique @map(name: "stripe_subscription_id")
  stripePriceId          String?   @map(name: "stripe_price_id")
  stripeCurrentPeriodEnd DateTime? @map(name: "stripe_current_period_end")
}
```

Expecting that it will redirect me to my dashboard but instead got this error:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.userApiLimit.findUnique()` invocation:


Error querying the database: Server error: `ERROR HY000 (1105): unavailable: unable to connect to branch 8yeh0d8jjckc'
```

Comment: May I know what database that you are using? MongoDB?

Comment: Yes with nextjs

Comment: seems like is the connection issue, you can check your MongoDB connection first

Comment: connection like,where from database but its showing invalid prisma.userApiLimit.findUnique()?

Comment: but your second Error message mentioned that "unable to connect to branch ...", for other queries same issue happen?

Comment: So, how can i fix that, any suggestion?

Comment: no, sorry it was my mistake.My database was asleep.It's working fine now.